# Playing FTP file with libvlc

Tags: c, ftp, libvlc

Is there a correct way for playing media located on a FTP server using libvlc?

After creating the media & media player,

```
libvlc_media_player_play
```

returns 0,

```
libvlc_media_player_get_state
```

returns libvlc_Error, and

```
libvlc_errmsg
```

returns "(null)"

The [official feature page for VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) lists FTP as supported input & the FTP link is playable using a VLC media player instance.

Code is pretty basic, same as most examples found online:

```
libvlc_media_t *m = libvlc_media_new_location( inst, "ftp://127.0.0.1:3531/path_to_movie.avi");
if ( !m )
    return false;

libvlc_media_player_t* mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m);
if ( !mp )
    return false;

libvlc_media_release(m);

libvlc_media_player_play(mp);
```

After play was called, nothing happens.
Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Is only ftp failing? Does http:// work ? If not already done you should use or append the `-v` argument in `libvlc_new()` in order to get verbose debug output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling verbose debug output (as suggested by gollum), found that the problem was due to wrong creation of `libvlc_media_t *m`.

Basically I have a URI checker to determine if link contains path to a local file or a remote file.

```
libvlc_media_t *m = IsLocalFile(pszMediaPath) ? libvlc_media_new_path(inst, pszMediaPath) : libvlc_media_new_location(inst, pszMediaPath);
```

`IsLocalFile(pszMediaPath)` was wrongly implemented (always returning true), resulting in calling of `libvlc_media_new_path` even for URIs, which caused `libvlc_media_player_play` to fail because the path to remote media was bogus.